# X value on flop enable equation

Tags: verilog

What happens if I have an `x` in my enable equation for a flop?

Take for example a flop coded like below

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
  if(en) q <= d;
end
```

So if `en` is `x` does that mean `reg q` will hold its previous state and not latch a new one (considering if statement with an `x` evaluates to 0/false) OR will it also be `x` in sims? 
And is this something that can vary based on simulators used?

Thanks!

Comment: https://static.docs.arm.com/arp0009/a/Verilog_X_Bugs.pdf

This can be an interesting read for the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any condition in the 'if' statement is considered 2-state. Verilog standard conversion from 'x' pr 'z' to a 2-state will produce '0'. So, your `if (en)` will be false if 'en' is 'x' or 'z', meaning that it will hold.

So, answering your question, `reg q` will hold the value.

same is true in system verilog if you assign a 4-state variable to a 2-state variable, i.e. 'bit';

Comment: Thanks Serge! I expected this and its proved in a VCS simulation I did too. I wanted to get more opinions on this but looks like I actually have a 2-2 for both the cases

Comment: And @Serge since this is actually dangerous (x optimistic behavior) how would you recommend catching such cases? Using embedded asserts that check for x value on this enable pin?

Comment: unfortunately, if you use standard verilog 4-state simulation, you need to write your 'if' statements in a specific way to check for -non-x conditions first. You can write a specific assertion as well. There is a open-source VRQ solution which rewrites existing rtl code to handle such cases. In commercial world VCS has the 'xprop' simulation mode that takes care of it as well. Not sure about other players.

Answer (score 1):

X-es will propagate from any FF input to all outputs. In fact they tend to propagate throughout a design like wildfire. Muxes, arithmetic, decoders almost everything quickly produces X if an input is X. 
There are a few exceptions like:

- OR gates where one input is high: the output is high even if another input is 'X'.
- AND gates where one input is low: the output is low even if another input is 'X'.

But a two-input OR gate where the inputs are 0 and X, will produce X.

The propagation of X-es is well defined and you should find the same behavior in all simulators.

Comment: Well it actually did not show me an X on the FF output when I simulated. It was just holding its state

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the latest standard IEEE1800-2012 for SystemVerilog specifies that a values in the predicate of an `if` conditional is `'bx`, the statement shall evaluate to false, ie same as if `en` were `'b0` (See section 12.4). The other answers here give a good understanding of what that value means in the larger context of RTL design.

Answer (score 0):

Since *X* refers to an undefined state, thus the output prediction is not possible in that case. Thus we would be getting a output as *X* itself from the flip-flop.

As stated by [oldfart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770129/x-value-on-flop-enable-equation) above, in case of AND & OR gates, the output depends on the presence of 1 & 0 logic input, respectively (at any of the other input terminals of that gate).